# What's the purpose of kvm, libvirt and libvirt-qemu groups in Linux?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I wanted to play a little bit with KVM on my Debian, and I installed the needed tools. The three groups showed up in the `/etc/group` file: `kvm` , `libvirt` and `libvirt-qemu` . What's the purpose of each of these groups?

For now I know that the `libvirt` group allows a regular user (via policykit) to connect to the libvirtd daemon without asking for root password, and hence it allows to create/remove/configure/manage of virtual machines.

I also know, that the `/dev/kvm` device has set the `kvm` group. What can a user do when he has read/write permissions to this device? Should I add a regular user to this group? If so, why?

I don't really know what's the purpose of the `libvirt-qemu` group. It looks like it's redundant, but many HowTos on the net suggest to add a regular user also to this group. Is this required?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See `/usr/share/doc/libvirt-daemon/README.Debian`: the `libvirt` group controls access to libvirt, through PolicyKit (as you determined), and `libvirt-qemu` is the user and group used to run system QEMU/KVM processes. You needn’t care about the latter, it’s an implementation detail, not a group end users need to be added to.

Membership of the `kvm` group grants access to `/dev/kvm`, which is necessary to run VMs using KVM. This is controlled using `uaccess` now, so the currently-active user on the console gets access automatically. `libvirt-qemu`’s primary group is `kvm` (specified in `/etc/passwd`, not `/etc/group`), which is how libvirt-managed VMs get access to KVM.