# Why a user could run qemu virtual machine in KVM mode without access to /dev/kvm on Debian 12 (bookworm)?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

One user account `A`, could run qemu VMs with kvm enabled, with the option `-enable-kvm`.

But user `A` does not have access to `/dev/kvm`. The related user groups and `/dev/kvm` permission is as follows.

```
$ id
uid=1004(A) gid=1004(A) groups=1004(A),100(users)
$ stat /dev/kvm
  File: /dev/kvm
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 0,5     Inode: 714         Links: 1     Device type: 10,232
Access: (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  104/     kvm)
```

According to [[SOLVED] Qemu with KVM fails, permission denied](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=69454) and other posts, users need to have access to `/dev/kvm` to use kvm-enabled qemu VMs.
This is usually done by putting a user into the group `kvm`.

Why user `A` is able to use qemu VMs with KVM?

---

System information:

- Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
- installed with a live iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian (and others), `/dev/kvm` is managed using `uaccess`; essentially, this provides access to certain devices to the user logged in “at the console” (*i.e.* sitting in front of the computer).

You can see this in action by checking the ACLs:

```
getfacl /dev/kvm
```

This should show an ACL granting read/write access to user A.

You’ll find the relevant `udev` rule in `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules`. See also [What's the purpose of kvm, libvirt and libvirt-qemu groups in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599651/86440)